# Create taskbar shortcut to launch PowerShell as Administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I'm using Windows 10 and whenever I run PowerShell, I almost exclusively need to run it in Administrator mode, however the taskbar shortcut only seems to enable this by right-clicking on the icon and selecting *Run as Administrator*.

[image]

Is there a way to make the shortcut itself simply run as Administrator?

Comment: While it's not what you've requested, you could switch Command Prompt to PowerShell in "Taskbar Properties" (right-click on the taskbar) and then use [Win+X, A] key sequence to run PowerShell as admin (the A key may depend on locale).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is:

1. Right-click the shortcut, then right-click Windows PowerShell and select **Properties**
2. Click the **Advanced** button (on the **Shortcut** tab) and check **Run as administrator**
3. Click OK twice.

[image]

Comment: Is the same possible for any other app? When I'm right-clicking my VS2017 taskbar shortcut, there is no `Properties` option. I'm using Win 10 1809 17763.194.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: Try using `Shift` + `Right Click` and make sure that the application is not running.